# how to write not in clause using springboot findAll() method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am try to get data from the database using **spring boot JPA and CRUD Repository findAll()** method with using `not in` clause but not find any where. There is any solution making dynamic query using findAll() method.

**Example:**

```
hql="select * from urlMaster urlmast where urlmast.urlcd not in (select distinct acturl.acuCd from ActionUrl acturl) order by urlmast.urlcd";
```

Currently I am just getting data from the urlMaster data. But i want **acturl.acuCd** `not in`  ActionUrl table.

**Repository class**:

```
public interface ActionUrlRepository extends CrudRepository<urlMaster, Long>,JpaRepository<urlMaster, Long> {

}
```

Service implementation:

```
actionurlrepository.findAll();
```

If there is any provision? Please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: Why would `findAll()` limit the result? I think I don't understand your question.

Comment: Jens Schauder!- i want data from database based on mansion query. Springboot already have some predefined methods like findAll()...etc and various repositories in springboot. As per the same i gona build criteria based on the that methods with not in clause. If you have any solution? let's post. I know @Query already have. i am looking that scenario. some internet guides tell solution for that but not get exact solution.-thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could put your query string in an @Query annotation, as described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

So something like :

```
public interface ActionUrlRepository extends JpaRepository<urlMaster, Long> {

    @Query("select * from urlMaster urlmast where urlmast.urlcd not in (select distinct acturl.acuCd from ActionUrl acturl) order by urlmast.urlcd")
    List<urlMaster> findByNotIn();
}
```

By the way, you don't need CrudRepository on the declaration, since JpaRepository already extends from it (via PagingAndSortingRepository).

Comment: Thanks ! I am expecting there is any provision with findll() includes ..?